# c# scanning api over rdp

Tags: c#, api, rdp

I am working on a scanning application in c# using an API. when I run the application locally it seems to work fine.
my problem is that the application is designated to be run as an RDP application and when I try to scan from it it fails saying that it can't find the scanner.

I was wondering if anybody knows of a way this can be achieved.

I would like the users to use their locally plugged in scanner but from the RDP application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable local devices and resources in the RDP client.

Options -> Local Resources -> Local devices and resources -> More...

Then make sure your scanner is selected, and that the device drivers for it are installed on the machine running the software.